# CV2 retain lines inside bounding polygon in image

Tags: python, opencv, mask, houghlinesp

I have an image. `img` in which I have detected lines using the approach [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html), the output is in `lines`. The code for this is

```py
img = cv2.imread('myfile.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5, 5),0)
edges = cv2.Canny(blur_gray, 50, 150)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 15, np.array([]), 50, 20)
```

Here `lines` is a list of lines having start and end coordinates `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`.

I need to only retain those lines which lie inside a bounding polygon, which is in an image `boundary` that has only the polygon edges in white, all other pixels are black. This image looks like this

[image: image polygon boundary]

How can I delete those lines in `lines` from `img` that do not lie inside the polygon I have in `boundary`? Is there an efficient way to do this without manually checking end-points of each line in `lines` to lie within the polygon?

Comment: You can use bitwise_and between Polygon and line. I can try to implement the method if you can show the previous code & input images.

Comment: If you show your code & put up an example image this would be a lot easier to answer

Comment: @EgeYıldırım I was thinking if it is possible to fill the polygon with ones and zeros outside and use it as a mask to do `bitwise_and` with endpoints of lines, could you suggest if there's a better way? Have updated with code and sample.

Comment: @DrBwts please see if the edit to the question is useful.

Comment: @S_S Its the first thing comes to my mind, bitwise operations are one of the fastest algorithms in image processing with O(n)  time complexity, I dont think there will be a more efficient way. in terms of speed at least.

Comment: @EgeYıldırım Thanks, but I am stuck at filling the interior of the polygon for now, can you give any pointers for that?

Comment: cv2.fillPoly(source_image, pts = [polygon_points], color =(255,255,255)) should work

Comment: @EgeYıldırım Thanks, how can I get `polygon_points` from the `boundary` image, which is the output of another `bitwise_and` operation between the original image and a mask?